# Difficulty in receiving response from HTTP client

Tags: java, xml, http, servlets

I am writing an application which will send XML over HTTP to a server, and receive XML as the response. I am able to send XML to the server but not able to receive the response.

This is my client code:

```
public void sendXMLToServer(){
    System.out.println("sendXMLToServer");
    String strURL = "http://localhost:9080/MockServerMachine/sendXMLPost";
    // Get file to be posted
    String strXMLFilename = "output.xml";
    File input = new File(strXMLFilename);
    // Prepare HTTP post
    System.out.println("junaud url "+ strURL);
    PostMethod post = new PostMethod(strURL);


 // Request content will be retrieved directly
    // from the input stream
    // Per default, the request content needs to be buffered
    // in order to determine its length.
    // Request body buffering can be avoided when
    // content length is explicitly specified
    try {
        post.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/xml");
        post.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/xml");

        post.setRequestEntity(new InputStreamRequestEntity(
                new FileInputStream(input), input.length()));
        HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
        int result = httpclient.executeMethod(post);
        String xmlResponse = post.getResponseBodyAsString();
        // Display status code
        System.out.println("Response status code jun: " + result);

        // Display response
        System.out.println("Response body: ");
        System.out.println(post.getResponseBodyAsString());
        post.releaseConnection();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (HttpException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the server side:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    //InputStream in = request.getInputStream();
        //URL xmlUrl = new URL(request.getRequestURL().toString());
    //InputStream in = xmlUrl.openStream();

    response.setContentLength(100);
//      PostMethod po = new PostMethod(request.getRequestURL().toString());
//      System.out.println("kikmk = "+po.getRequestEntity());

    try {
        // read this file into InputStream
        //InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("c:\\file.xml");
        InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
        // write the inputStream to a FileOutputStream
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("c:\\junaidAhmedJameel.xml"));

        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            System.out.println(new String (bytes));
            System.out.println(read);
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }

        inputStream.close();
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        System.out.println("New file created!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

      }
```

Can anyone help me out here? Any sample client/server example for sending XML over HTTP would be great.

Comment: Well what *does* happen? Are any exceptions thrown? It would really help if you could tidy up the code in your question - I reckon about half the server side lines are either comments or just empty, and the indentation's broken too...

Comment: I don't get any exception, response status code is 200 and response body is blank.

Comment: Well what does the logging in the server side show? Have you managed to *read* any bytes?

Comment: I am able to read the xml in server code, But Client is not receiving any response content.

Comment: See the answers - what response content were you *expecting* to get, and where do you believe your code is writing that response?

Comment: @user966682 What does Fiddler show? Is it the server failing to send the response or the client failing to read it? By looking – with Fiddler – at what is passed across the network you make debugging much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, spotted it. Look here:

```
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("c:\\junaidAhmedJameel.xml"));
```

That's just going to write to the local disk. You're not writing any content to the response stream. It's not clear what you *want* to write to the response stream, but there's a conspicuous absence of calls to `response.getWriter()` or `response.getOutputStream()`.

You're setting the content length to 100, but not actually sending any content. Note that hard-coding the content-length is almost certainly the wrong thing to do anyway... but it's *definitely* the wrong thing to do when you're not sending any content...

Comment: Thanks Skeet it got the problem,

Answer (score 0):

You never generate any response content in your server code. You just set the length to 100.